# Store 100 strings and search file i/o java

Tags: java, arrays

In this program I am trying write a program that reads the first 100 strings from a set of text files and then counts how many times those strings appear in the whole of each file. Well I keep getting a crazy output and I asked this question earlier but butchered it. One thing has changed but now my output is null = 0. for 100 times

my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KveOi.png

```
    package program6;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

 public class Program6 {

public static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "myths.txt";
public static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME2 = "pnp.txt";
public static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME3 = "tsawyer.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in = null;
    Scanner fin = null;
    Scanner fin2 = null;
    Scanner fin3 = null;
    String[] character = new String[100];
    int[] counter = new int[100];


    try {
        fin = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE_NAME));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error opening the file " + INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        fin2 = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE_NAME2));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error opening the file " + INPUT_FILE_NAME2);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        fin3 = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE_NAME3));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error opening the file " + INPUT_FILE_NAME3);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println("Word:              Count:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(character[i] + "         " + counter[i]);
    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace

```
System.out.println(character + "         " + counter);
```

by

```
    System.out.println(character[i] + "         " + counter[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line `System.out.println(character + "         " + counter);`

It should be:

```
System.out.println(character[i] + "         " + counter[i]);
```

Comment: wow lol thanks! Now my output is all null = 0. I cant believe I missed that. My lack of sleep has caught up to me.

Comment: Not a problem, Sujan beat me to it though :)